# How to add a scrollbar to tkinter application?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an simple database based software for my personal report generation work. But the my GUI has more length. So I need to add srollbar I tried to use canvas and frame and previous tutorials. But mostly it is working for `Listbox` but not for whole application window.

My code is given below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
scroll = Scrollbar(window)
scroll.grid(column = 5, row = 0, rowspan = 20)
window.wm_title('Water Quality Testing Laboratory')

frame1 = Canvas(window)
frame1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
# Headings

leb1 = Label(frame1, text = "Water Quality Testing Laboratory", fg = 'black')
leb1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 20 , columnspan = 2)

leb2 = Label(frame1, text = "Water Knowledge Centre (WKC)", fg = 'black')
leb2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 20 , columnspan = 2)

leb3 = Label(frame1, text = "The DHAN Academy (TDA), Madurai", fg = 'black')
leb3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W, padx = 20 ,columnspan = 2 )

leb4 = Label(frame1, text = "TEST ANALYSIS REPORT", fg = 'black', bg = 'grey', font = 32 )
leb4.grid(row = 4, column = 0, ipady = 10, pady = 10,  columnspan = 5, sticky= EW ,  )


leb5 = Label(frame1, text = 'tda logo')
leb5.grid(row = 1, column = 4, padx = 20  )

# Sample Details

leb6 = Label(frame1, text = 'Customer Details:')
leb6.grid(column = 0, row = 6, sticky = E, padx = 20)
entry_customer = Entry(frame1)
entry_customer.grid(column = 1, row = 6, columnspan = 4, ipadx = 250)

leb7 = Label(frame1, text = 'Sample Number:')
leb7.grid(column = 0, row = 7, sticky = E, padx = 20)
entry_sampleNumber = Entry(frame1)
entry_sampleNumber.grid(column = 1, row = 7)

leb8 = Label(frame1, text = 'Sample Drawn By:')
leb8.grid(column = 3, row = 7, sticky = E)
entry_sampleDrawn = Entry(frame1)
entry_sampleDrawn.grid(column = 4, row = 7)

leb9 = Label(frame1, text = 'Sample Drawn Date:')
leb9.grid(column = 0, row = 8, sticky = E, padx = 20)
entry_sampleDrawnDate = Entry(frame1)
entry_sampleDrawnDate.grid(column = 1, row = 8)

leb10 = Label(frame1, text = 'Sample Reached Lab on:')
leb10.grid(column = 3, row = 8, sticky = E)
entry_sampleReached = Entry(frame1)
entry_sampleReached.grid(column = 4, row = 8)

leb11 = Label(frame1, text = 'Test Start Date:')
leb11.grid(column = 0, row = 9, sticky = E, padx = 20)
entry_testStart = Entry(frame1)
entry_testStart.grid(column = 1, row = 9)

leb12 = Label(frame1, text = 'Test End Date:')
leb12.grid(column = 3, row = 9, sticky = E)
entry_testEnd = Entry(frame1)
entry_testEnd.grid(column = 4, row = 9)

leb13 = Label(frame1, text = 'Sample Reference:')
leb13.grid(column = 0, row = 10, padx =20, sticky = E)
entry_sampleReference = Entry(frame1)
entry_sampleReference.grid(column = 1, row = 10, columnspan = 4, ipadx = 250)


## Test Results

leb14 = Label(frame1, text = '1. Physical Parameters')
leb14.grid(column = 0, row = 11, pady = 10)

leb15 = Label(frame1, text = 'Sr. No.', bg = 'grey')
leb15.grid(column = 0, row = 12, sticky = NSEW)

leb16 = Label(frame1, text= 'Parameters', bg = 'grey')
leb16.grid(column = 1, row = 12, sticky = NSEW)

leb17 = Label(frame1, text= 'Acceptable Limit as per BIS', wraplength = 150, bg = 'grey' )
leb17.grid(column = 2, row = 12, sticky = NSEW)

leb18 = Label(frame1, text= 'Permissible Limit as per BIS', wraplength = 150, bg = 'grey' )
leb18.grid(column = 3, row = 12, sticky = NSEW)

leb19 = Label(frame1, text = 'Results',bg = 'grey')
leb19.grid(column = 4, row = 12, sticky = NSEW)

# Physical Parameters
leb20 = Label(frame1, text = '1')
leb20.grid(column = 0, row = 13)

# Appearance
leb21 = Label(frame1, text = 'Appearance')
leb21.grid(column = 1, row = 13, sticky = W )

leb22 = Label(frame1, text = '-')
leb22.grid(column = 2, row = 13)

leb23 = Label(frame1, text = '')
leb23.grid(column = 3, row = 13)

entry_appearance = Entry(frame1)
entry_appearance.grid(column = 4, row = 13)

# Colour
leb24 = Label(frame1, text = '2')
leb24.grid(column = 0, row = 14)

leb25 = Label(frame1, text = 'Colour')
leb25.grid(column = 1, row = 14, sticky = W )

leb26 = Label(frame1, text = '-')
leb26.grid(column = 2, row = 14 )

leb27 = Label(frame1, text = '')
leb27.grid(column = 3, row = 14, sticky = W )

entry_colour = Entry(frame1)
entry_colour.grid(column = 4, row = 14)

# Odour
leb28 = Label(frame1, text = '3')
leb28.grid(column = 0, row = 15)

leb29 = Label(frame1, text = 'Odour')
leb29.grid(column = 1, row = 15, sticky = W )

leb30 = Label(frame1, text = 'Unobjectionable')
leb30.grid(column = 2, row = 15, sticky = W )

leb31 = Label(frame1, text = 'Unobjectionable')
leb31.grid(column = 3, row = 15, sticky = W )

entry_odour = Entry(frame1)
entry_odour.grid(column = 4, row = 15)

# Turbidity NTU
leb32 = Label(frame1, text = '4')
leb32.grid(column = 0, row = 16)

leb33 = Label(frame1, text = 'Turbidity NTU')
leb33.grid(column = 1, row = 16, sticky = W )

leb34 = Label(frame1, text = '1')
leb34.grid(column = 2, row = 16 )

leb35 = Label(frame1, text = '5')
leb35.grid(column = 3, row = 16)

entry_turbidity = Entry(frame1)
entry_turbidity.grid(column = 4, row = 16)

# Electrical Conductivity (EC)
leb36 = Label(frame1, text = '5')
leb36.grid(column = 0, row = 17)

leb37 = Label(frame1, text = 'Electrical Conductivity (EC)')
leb37.grid(column = 1, row = 17, sticky = W )

leb38 = Label(frame1, text = '-')
leb38.grid(column = 2, row = 17)

leb39 = Label(frame1, text = '')
leb39.grid(column = 3, row = 17, sticky = W )

entry_electricalConductivity = Entry(frame1)
entry_electricalConductivity.grid(column = 4, row = 17)

# Total Dissolved Solids (TDS)
leb40 = Label(frame1, text = '6')
leb40.grid(column = 0, row = 18)

leb41 = Label(frame1, text = 'Total Dissolved Solids (TDS)')
leb41.grid(column = 1, row = 18, sticky = W )

leb42 = Label(frame1, text = '500')
leb42.grid(column = 2, row = 18)

leb43 = Label(frame1, text = '2000')
leb43.grid(column = 3, row = 18)

entry_electricalConductivity = Entry(frame1)
entry_electricalConductivity.grid(column = 4, row = 18)

# Chemical Parameters
leb44 = Label(frame1, text = '2. Chemical Parameters')
leb44.grid(column = 0, row = 19, pady = 10)

# Headers
leb45 = Label(frame1, text = 'Sr. No.', bg = 'grey')
leb45.grid(column = 0, row = 20, sticky = NSEW)

leb46 = Label(frame1, text= 'Parameters', bg = 'grey')
leb46.grid(column = 1, row = 20, sticky = NSEW)

leb47 = Label(frame1, text= 'Acceptable Limit as per BIS', wraplength = 150, bg = 'grey' )
leb47.grid(column = 2, row = 20, sticky = NSEW)

leb48 = Label(frame1, text= 'Permissible Limit as per BIS', wraplength = 150, bg = 'grey' )
leb48.grid(column = 3, row = 20, sticky = NSEW)

leb49 = Label(frame1, text = 'Results',bg = 'grey')
leb49.grid(column = 4, row = 20, sticky = NSEW)

# pH
leb50 = Label(frame1, text = '1')
leb50.grid(column = 0, row = 21)

leb51 = Label(frame1, text = 'pH')
leb51.grid(column = 1, row = 21, sticky = W )

leb52 = Label(frame1, text = '6.5 - 8.5')
leb52.grid(column = 2, row = 21)

leb53 = Label(frame1, text = '6.5 - 8.5')
leb53.grid(column = 3, row = 21)

entry_ph = Entry(frame1)
entry_ph.grid(column = 4, row = 21)

# PH Alkalinity as Caco3
leb54 = Label(frame1, text = '2')
leb54.grid(column = 0, row = 22)

leb55 = Label(frame1, text = 'PH Alkalinity as Caco3')
leb55.grid(column = 1, row = 22, sticky = W )

leb56 = Label(frame1, text = '-')
leb56.grid(column = 2, row = 22)

leb57 = Label(frame1, text = '-')
leb57.grid(column = 3, row = 22)

entry_phAlkalinity = Entry(frame1)
entry_phAlkalinity.grid(column = 4, row = 22)

# Total Alkalinity as CaCO3
leb58 = Label(frame1, text = '3')
leb58.grid(column = 0, row = 23)

leb59 = Label(frame1, text = 'Total Alkalinity as CaCO3')
leb59.grid(column = 1, row = 23, sticky = W )

leb60 = Label(frame1, text = '200')
leb60.grid(column = 2, row = 23)

leb61 = Label(frame1, text = '600')
leb61.grid(column = 3, row = 23)

entry_totalAlkalinity = Entry(frame1)
entry_totalAlkalinity.grid(column = 4, row = 23)

# Total Hardness as CaCO3
leb62 = Label(frame1, text = '4')
leb62.grid(column = 0, row = 24)

leb63 = Label(frame1, text = 'Total Hardness as CaCO3')
leb63.grid(column = 1, row = 24, sticky = W )

leb64 = Label(frame1, text = '200')
leb64.grid(column = 2, row = 24)

leb65 = Label(frame1, text = '600')
leb65.grid(column = 3, row = 24)

entry_totalHardness = Entry(frame1)
entry_totalHardness.grid(column = 4, row = 24)

# Calcium as Ca
leb66 = Label(frame1, text = '5')
leb66.grid(column = 0, row = 25)

leb67 = Label(frame1, text = 'Calcium as Ca')
leb67.grid(column = 1, row = 25, sticky = W )

leb68 = Label(frame1, text = '75')
leb68.grid(column = 2, row = 25)

leb69 = Label(frame1, text = '100')
leb69.grid(column = 3, row = 25)

entry_ca = Entry(frame1)
entry_ca.grid(column = 4, row = 25)

# Magnesium as Mg
leb70 = Label(frame1, text = '6')
leb70.grid(column = 0, row = 26)

leb71 = Label(frame1, text = 'Magnesium as Mg')
leb71.grid(column = 1, row = 26, sticky = W )

leb72 = Label(frame1, text = '30')
leb72.grid(column = 2, row = 26)

leb73 = Label(frame1, text = '150')
leb73.grid(column = 3, row = 26)

entry_mg = Entry(frame1)
entry_mg.grid(column = 4, row = 26)

# Total iron as Fe
leb74 = Label(frame1, text = '7')
leb74.grid(column = 0, row = 27)

leb75 = Label(frame1, text = 'Total iron as Fe')
leb75.grid(column = 1, row = 27, sticky = W )

leb76 = Label(frame1, text = '0.1')
leb76.grid(column = 2, row = 27)

leb77 = Label(frame1, text = '1.0')
leb77.grid(column = 3, row = 27)

entry_fe = Entry(frame1)
entry_fe.grid(column = 4, row = 27)

# Sodium as Na
leb78 = Label(frame1, text = '7')
leb74.grid(column = 0, row = 27)

leb75 = Label(frame1, text = 'Total iron as Fe')
leb75.grid(column = 1, row = 27, sticky = W )

leb76 = Label(frame1, text = '0.1')
leb76.grid(column = 2, row = 27)

leb77 = Label(frame1, text = '1.0')
leb77.grid(column = 3, row = 27)

entry_fe = Entry(frame1)
entry_fe.grid(column = 4, row = 27)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you ask me, i think fr a scroll bar to work you shuold be having all values inside of a list or something similar to that like a treeview.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7414759)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Treeview` as mention by @Cool Cloud. Treeviews have scroll option even though we cannot visually see it on the screen.

To add scrollbars visually on the screen, you can use the following code after creating your widget which needs scrollbars:

```
name_of_scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient = VERTICAL)
name_of_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
```

Then use the `yscrollcommand` in the widget and set its value to `name_of_scrollbar.set`
Use another line to make the scrollbar working:

```
name_of_scrollbar.config(command=name_of_widget.yview)
```

Note: You can also add horizontal scrollbars to your widgets using the same procedure above with little tweaks:

1. Set ORIENT option to VERTICAL
2. Change side and fill to BOTTOM and X respectively.
3. At last, change command to `name_of_widget.xview`